# Is there a way to apply a condition to a regex in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm filtering a column in pandas but want to keep certain values.

My goal is to change the values all players that aren't Federer, Nadal and Djokovic to "Other" so

Before:

```
winner_name 

Federer     
Nadal       
Djokovic    
Kyrgios    
Hewitt
```

After:

```
winner_name 

Federer     
Nadal       
Djokovic    
Other    
Other
```

I've tried this

```
df['winner_name'] = df['winner_name'].replace(to_replace=r"^(.(?<!Roger Federer))*?$", value='other',regex=True)
```

but this replaces all the values other than Federer to 'other'.

```
winner_name

Federer     
Other       
Other    
Other    
Other
```

I wish to apply the conditional to more than one value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.where` and `isin` are enough here:

```
df['winner_name'] = np.where(df['winner_name'].isin(['Federer', 'Nadal', 'Djokovic']),
                             df['winner_name'], 'Other')
```